# Maximize 2-Norm of Matrix and Phase Shift Vector Product

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the problem writing in an equation:
$$\max_{\mathbf{x}}\|\mathbf{Ax}\|_2,\quad\text{s.t. }|\mathbf{x}_n|=1,~n=1,2,\cdots,N,$$
where $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{M\times N}$ and $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times1}$.

I have found a lot of questions maximizing the $\ell$-2 norm of a matrix and vector product.
But unfortunately, they have the constraint on $\|\mathbf{x}\|_2$ instead of a **phase shift** constraint that the modulus of each vector element is $1$.

> In my specific problem, the modulus of each entry in $\mathbf{A}$ is also $1$.

I have tried several methods without success because I cannot utilize the phase shift property well.